# MikTeX update error

Tags: miktex, miktex-update

Update of my MikTeX portable on Win 7 failed this morning (Dec 24th, 2016). The error message is given below. Prior to that a lot of packages have been removed, obviously some critical ones among them as well. My offline DB was syncronized. Was my update too early or what might be the cause?[image]

Comment: When did you the update before this one?

Comment: Try uninstalling MiKTeX and then reinstalling it.

Comment: It looks as if you can't start the update manager GUI. Try to call it from the command line in the trash-menu of miktex portable. See also my comment here https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2546/#7751 (don't use the `--repository-release-state=next` option).

Answer (score 10):

Analyzing mpm logs and miktex sources gives a hint that MiKTeX Update Manager incorrectly handles a situation when no proxy is set. So I entered the proxy (*Connections Settings...* button) (I used `uk11.frigate.org`), after which the update process worked.

Comment: I just should add that this procedure worked for me with both a 32-bit portable and 64-bit stationary installation.

Comment: Once this has been done, you don't need the proxy settings anymore and it seems to fix itself after the one update of doom.

Comment: This worked for me, too. And the proxy settings can be removed after that. Thanks.

Comment: I am facing the same problem but could not fix it. Can you please provide some pictorial suggestions? I don't know how to enter proxy settings

Comment: In the connection setting button, there is no box to put URL.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem this morning (1st: update of the system -> went fine; then update of the packages with error as above) and tried answer 2 (proxy setting). As I have no proxy, I just checked and unchecked the box. Then tried "let me choose repository" and manually selected one. After this the update worked.

P.S. There was an error messages at the end "executed process did not succed", but there seem to be no furtehr update.

Update: There seems to be a problem with the "nearest site selection" Maintainance "Update formats" needed to load multiple packages, which also only worked after manually selecting repository.

Comment: I can confirm that this worked for me. I was getting the same error as reported by the OP after the second update, and the fix was to click "Connection Settings" and then tick the box "Use a proxy server" and then immediately untick it again. Afterwards, I was able to proceed through the wizard as usual.

Answer (score 1):

Updating an old MiKTeX installation or installing the current `basic-miktex-2.9.6161` and updating it leads to the described error. (Such things should *never* happen, but it is not the first time.) The suggested deinstall + reinstall does *not* help.

The combination of packages in the 2016-12-23 repos seems to be broken (at least for some systems). I suggest: **Do not update and wait for another release**.

As of 2017-01-05, [MiKTeX.org writes](https://miktex.org/alert/update-wizard-2017-01):

> MiKTeX Update Wizard issues
>
> Last edited: 1/5/2017 10:06:29 AM
>
> The latest Version of the update wizard has issues on some Windows Systems.
>   The problem [has been identified](https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2564/) and a fix is available here:
>
> https://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/support/update

**Update**

A few days later, the next version of MikTeX worked again.

Answer (score 1):

The same has happened to me today. I fixed the issue doing the following steps:

1. Uninstall MiKTeX completely (after uninstalling from the Control Panel, I had to manually delete the folder in Program Files, for some reason).
2. Install using the basic installer.
3. Run MiKTeX Update.
4. Run MiKTeX Update (once again, yes, first time it will allow you to install just some basic updates).
5. Compile the document.

This is what has worked for me so far. I have left the on-the-fly package install as "ask me first".

*Note*: After step 2 I tried compiling directly, but after installing the required packages I got incompatibilities between `biber` and `biblatex`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on one of my machines. Running the update from a DOS prompt worked. After that, I tried checking and unchecking the proxy box as suggested in one of the earlier answers. After that, the update wizard works again.

Answer (score 1):

I was also experiencing the update - the reason was I had a document opened and a compilation in progress:-D simply stop it and close the MikTeX then check for updates from any random source.

Comment: Note this is not a fix for the original error message (shown in question) i.e. a  **connection** error MiKTeX will tell you off by means of a very explanatory error message for trying to update open files.