# Internal error: Unable to update MiKTeX

Tags: miktex-update

After running the MiKTeX update wizard once yesterday it stopped working. The update removed the packages

- garamondx
- miktex-graphics-bin-x64-2.9
- miktex-xdvipdfmx-bin-x64-2.9

and installed the packages

- miktex-bin-x64-2.9
- miktex-epstopdfbin-x64-2.9
- miktex-md5-bin-x64-2.9

The update log says

```
2017-01-03 11:45:11,050+0100 INFO  Update - starting: Update Wizard (MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit)
2017-01-03 11:46:08,378+0100 INFO  FileCopyPage - starting package maintenance...
2017-01-03 11:46:08,379+0100 INFO  FileCopyPage - installation directory: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9"
2017-01-03 11:46:08,379+0100 INFO  FileCopyPage - package repository: http://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
2017-01-03 11:46:08,452+0100 INFO  FileCopyPage - lightweight database digest: 8b7e5e14ebc0805350eddfca3bbc71bc
2017-01-03 11:46:08,454+0100 INFO  FileCopyPage - going to download 7940544 bytes
2017-01-03 11:46:08,454+0100 INFO  FileCopyPage - going to install 9 file(s) (3 package(s))
2017-01-03 11:46:08,455+0100 INFO  FileCopyPage - going to remove 199 file(s) (3 package(s))
2017-01-03 11:46:08,457+0100 INFO  FileCopyPage - downloading http://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
2017-01-03 11:46:10,934+0100 INFO  FileCopyPage - 7902501 bytes, 3116.84 KB/Sec
2017-01-03 11:46:11,001+0100 INFO  FileCopyPage - extracting files from miktex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
2017-01-03 11:46:11,640+0100 INFO  FileCopyPage - downloading http://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-epstopdf-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
2017-01-03 11:46:11,670+0100 INFO  FileCopyPage - 29660 bytes, 998.79 KB/Sec
2017-01-03 11:46:11,674+0100 INFO  FileCopyPage - extracting files from miktex-epstopdf-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
2017-01-03 11:46:11,724+0100 INFO  FileCopyPage - downloading http://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-md5-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
2017-01-03 11:46:11,742+0100 INFO  FileCopyPage - 8383 bytes, 481.56 KB/Sec
2017-01-03 11:46:11,744+0100 INFO  FileCopyPage - extracting files from miktex-md5-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
2017-01-03 11:46:11,789+0100 INFO  FileCopyPage - removing package garamondx...
2017-01-03 11:46:12,002+0100 INFO  FileCopyPage - removing package miktex-graphics-bin-x64-2.9...
2017-01-03 11:46:12,042+0100 INFO  FileCopyPage - removing package miktex-xdvipdfmx-bin-x64-2.9...
2017-01-03 11:46:12,084+0100 INFO  FileCopyPage - running 'mpm --register-components --verbose --admin'
2017-01-03 11:46:12,461+0100 INFO  FileCopyPage - configuring fontconfig\config\fonts.conf
2017-01-03 11:46:12,558+0100 INFO  FileCopyPage - registering C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin/x64\MiKTeX209-core.dll
2017-01-03 11:46:12,562+0100 INFO  FileCopyPage - registering C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin/x64\MiKTeX209-core-PS.dll
2017-01-03 11:46:12,581+0100 INFO  FileCopyPage - registering C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin/x64\MiKTeX209-packagemanager.dll
2017-01-03 11:46:12,601+0100 INFO  FileCopyPage - registering C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin/x64\MiKTeX209-packagemanager-PS.dll
2017-01-03 11:46:12,642+0100 INFO  FileCopyPage - running 'initexmf --update-fndb --verbose --admin'
2017-01-03 11:46:12,851+0100 INFO  FileCopyPage - Skipping user root directory (C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2017-01-03 11:46:12,853+0100 INFO  FileCopyPage - Skipping user root directory (C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2017-01-03 11:46:12,921+0100 INFO  FileCopyPage - Creating fndb for common root directory (C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2017-01-03 11:46:21,238+0100 INFO  FileCopyPage - Creating fndb for common root directory ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9")...
2017-01-03 11:46:21,277+0100 INFO  FileCopyPage - running 'initexmf --force --mklinks --verbose --admin'
2017-01-03 11:46:21,811+0100 INFO  FileCopyPage - initexmf: warning: The link target "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-xdvipdfmx.exe" does not exist.
2017-01-03 11:46:21,848+0100 INFO  FileCopyPage - running 'initexmf --mkmaps --mklangs --verbose --admin'
2017-01-03 11:46:22,223+0100 INFO  FileCopyPage - Creating language.dat, language.dat.lua and language.def...
2017-01-03 11:46:22,225+0100 INFO  FileCopyPage - Entering administrative mode...
2017-01-03 11:46:22,228+0100 INFO  FileCopyPage - Parsing config file "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\config\updmap.cfg"...
```

... and then continues with the font maps.

Whenever I try to start the update wizard I get the following log entries (probably not very helpful):

```
2017-01-03 11:46:47,057+0100 INFO  Update - starting: Update Wizard (MiKTeX 2.9.6200 64-bit)
2017-01-03 11:46:53,127+0100 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2017-01-03 11:46:53,127+0100 INFO  FileCopyPage - Error: MiKTeX encountered an internal error.
```

Updating the FNDB and Installing packages via package manager work as expected.

I’m on Win7 Enterprise SP1.

Comment: See the most upvoted answer in this thread: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/345485/80972