# How can I make dvisvgm work with non-default fonts?

Tags: dvisvgm

When running dvisvgm to convert a dvi to svg, I get the error `WARNING: can't embed font 'mi-kurierri'`. (Or something corresponding to any non-default font I try)

It used to work, but I tried to change fonts, as advised by [the LaTeX font catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/kurier/), by adding these lines to the doc's preamble:

```
\usepackage[math]{kurier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

I'm using MikTeX 2.9 on Windows 10. Generating dvi files with non-default fonts works fine. It's just the dvisvgm step that gets tripped up by the font change.

More info:

- The [dvisvgm FAQ](http://dvisvgm.bplaced.net/FAQ) addresses this error, saying that a probable cause is
  that the font is not available in the current TeX environment. I
  don't think this is the case for me, because dvisvgm.exe is in the
  same directory as latex.exe, which handles the fonts just fine.
- My MikTeX update wizard is broken, a la [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/345485/miktex-update-error), so I downloaded the newest version of dvisvgm separately and replaced the old dvisvgm.exe with the new one. (The old one wouldn't even work with the default font.)

### Edit (solved)

I had started with a template file that happened to have `\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}`, which is for Chinese. Not too surprising that this caused a conflict when I tried to change English font packages. Thanks to ShreevatsaR for the comment which prompted me to simplify the file rather than taking the error at face value.

If anyone with a deeper understanding of TeX could help me understand how the ctex package conflicted with the non-default font packages but not the default-font English characters, I'd be curious to know.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you add a minimal example of a document that uses those fonts, and on which `dvisvgm` fails? (Note that TeX only needs the font metrics to generate the DVI file—and you can get font metrics without even having the font—while `dvisgm` would need the actual font (the shapes of the glyphs). So that may be a problem, but there's not enough detail here to be sure.)

Comment: Glad that it works for you now. But even to answer your follow-up question (why it wasn't working earlier), it would help to have a minimal document (with the `\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}`) in which there's a failure :-)